# JHipster serve Angular frontend separately - Cors problems

Tags: jhipster

We started using JHipster monolith and now we have to separate the frontend for several reasons. Building and deploying the angular www folder works. However, we always get a Cors error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:9000/api/authenticate

The backend allows Cors (also runs in dev, default is cors enabled)

Do I have to modify the proxy.conf.json? Any other easy workarounds?

Comment: Have you followed instructions from https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes. I just fixed the bug. I forgot the http:// in the webpack.common.js SERVER_API_URL.